# what is retrieved in model event life cycle on laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

laravel  has many event models,like `creating` , `saved`  and etc.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#events

The only thing I do not understand. The event is `retrieved` and `restored`.Can anyone explain this to me with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on laravel docs The retrieved event will fire when an existing model is retrieved from the database.

for example if you have a User model in your application you must define code like below in User Model .

```
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'retrieved' => \App\Events\UserRetrieved::class,
];
```

Comment: please example for model event
@kaivan-alimohammadi

Answer (score 4):

The **retrieved** event fires when you retrieve a model.

The **restored** event fires when you restore a model after [soft deletion](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#soft-deleting).

You can look at sources to get deep understanding of the Eloquent workflow. Look at [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/SoftDeletes.php#L105) for **restored** and [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L320) for **retrieved**.

So, for instance you can create an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers) for the User model and implement there listeners for events you are interested in.

```
<?php
// app/Observers/UserObserver.php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\User;

class UserObserver
{
    public function retrieved(User $user)
    {
        //
    }

    public function restored(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And then register the observer in your AppServiceProvider.

```
<?php
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\User;
use App\Observers\UserObserver;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        User::observe(UserObserver::class);
    }

    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```